# Load Balancer in On-Premise High Availability Kubernetes cluster formation

Tags: kubernetes

I am currently trying to form a high availability Kubernetes cluster having 5 worker nodes and 3 master in on-premise server. I learned about implementation of high availability cluster by checking its documentation. Also I understood the implementation of HA cluster on AWS cloud or Azure cloud using Load Balancer functionality from appropriate cloud provider.

My confusion is that, when I am creating the same high availability Kubernetes cluster in my on-premise server, then how I can use the Load Balancer functionality in implementation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use keepalived to setup the load balancer for master on your on premise setup. The keepalived daemon can be used to monitor services or systems and to automatically failover to a standby if problems occur. There will be one Active server on the master and other two master will be in backup mode.

I have written a blog on how to setup kubernetes highly available cluster on premise. You can find it at below link:

https://velotio.com/blog/2018/6/15/kubernetes-high-availability-kubeadm

I have used keepalived to setup the load balancer in above blog on my on-premise cluster.

Comment: How did you setup virtual ip for the three masters

Comment: On the blog mentioned in answer if you check setup load balancer section, in file /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf we are providing a virtual IP address which is acting as a load balancer ip and all the request will go to that IP address and then it will forward it to one of the master. The virtual IP is stick to one master and if that master fails the virtual IP will be moved to other master and the api request will get served from other master without interruption

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is that we put cluster of loadbalancers (simple nginx in reverse proxy in HA) in front of the K8s API and in front of the Ingress.